# What syntax would I use to have my program disregard underscores, punctuation, and all other camelcase etc

Tags: java, linux, json, jackson

I am using the Jackson library. I have added in the dependencies.

Here is the syntax I have used so far, I have passed in an object into this method called result.

```
 private void getSampleFromJson(List<SampleProjectDto> result) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
  URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/test.json");
  File jsonFile = new File(url.getFile());
  System.out.println("Full path of file: " + jsonFile);

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  InputStream is = Test_Project.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.json");
  SampleDto testObj = mapper.readValue(is, SampleDto.class);
  System.out.println(testObj.getCreatedByUrl());
```

}

Now the file that I am reading, the file is a text file with the json in it. My problem is that a lot of my variables and things in the file have underscores, and are in camel case, and this is causing my program not to run. What can I do to not have to change my entire json file, is there a programming method or statement that I can put in to have it ignore all these punctuations and camel case and make it all nice and into snake case for this method to be able to work and so will my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might not understand the concrete problem you have, but mapping POJO fields to JSON properties can be done as follows.

You either have to use [JsonProperty](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotation:

```
class SampleDto{
    @JsonProperty("first_name")  // property name JSON
    protected String firstName;
    protected String getFirstName(){return firstName;}
}
```

or configure the `ObjectMapper` with a [PropertyNamingStrategy](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html):

```
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
    PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
```

You can even implement your own `PropertyNamingStrategy` if you want, it's up to you.